# background-size in IE not working 1

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have problem with background-size in ie.

It's the meta tag in my html:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

CSS part:

```
background-image: url('images/nav-logo.png');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 108px;
    height: 86px;       
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/nav-logo.png', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/nav-logo.png', sizingMethod='scale')"
```

I opened my page in ie 11, but size doesn't changing.
Help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this :

```
 background: url(images/nav-logo.svg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Comment: It would be really nice if you could upvote too :) Happy Coding!